# How to send email with multiple addresses in C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I'm trying to send emails using gmail's username and password in a Windows application. However, the following code is sending the mail to only the first email address when I collect multiple email address in my StringBuilder instance.

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress(username, DefaultSender);
var toAddress = new MailAddress(builder.ToString());//builder reference having multiple email address

string subject = txtSubject.Text;
string body = txtBody.Text; ;
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = HostName,
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
    //Timeout = 1000000

};
var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    IsBodyHtml = chkHtmlBody.Checked

};

if (System.IO.File.Exists(txtAttechments.Text))
{
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attechment = new  Attachment(txtAttechments.Text);
    message.Attachments.Add(attechment);
}

if(this.Enabled)
    this.Enabled = false;

smtp.Send(message);
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I sort out my problem?

Comment: Does the builder delimit by "," or ";"?

Comment: Builder instance having email address delimited by ",": "email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best bet is to `message.To.Add()` each of your `MailAddress`es individually. I think early versions of .Net were happier to parse apart comma or semicolon separated email addresses than the more recent runtime versions.

Comment: message.To.Add(builder.ToString()) code is working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

The code is actually

```
message.To.Add("xxx@gmail.com, yyy@gmail.com");
```

this one can work in .net 3.5

if you use

```
message.To.Add( new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com, yyy@gmail.com"));
```

this won't work in .net 3.5